# Split NSMutableArray into different Arrays

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

All,

In a mutable Array I have multiple Arrays, In each Array i have multiple dictionaries, In the Dictionaries i have common Values, Based on the Values I have to Group an Array/Dictionary below is sample Array

> (

```
(
    {
        name = "attribute_Subject";
        value = English;
    },
    {
        name = "attribute_class";
        value = Fourth;
    },
),
(
    {
        name = "attribute_Subject";
        value = English;
    },
    {
        name = "attribute_class";
        value = Fifth;
    },
),
(
    {
        name = "attribute_Subject";
        value = Maths;
    },
    {
        name = "attribute_class";
        value = Fourth;
    },
),
(
    {
        name = "attribute_Subject";
        value = Science;
    },
    {
        name = "attribute_class";
        value = Fourth;
    },
),
(
    {
        name = "attribute_Subject";
        value = English;
    },
    {
        name = "attribute_class";
        value = Sixth;
    },
),
(
    {
        name = "attribute_Subject";
        value = Maths;
    },
    {
        name = "attribute_class";
        value = Sixth;
    },
),
```

)

**If you see the Arrays We have English in Three Arrays, I want that three Arrays in a separate Array and same for "Science" and Maths**

Can we use predicates?

Can any one help

Comment: Could you show expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code will be helpful.
 NSLog(@"%@", muteArray);

```
 NSArray *valuesArray = [muteArray valueForKey:@"value"];
    NSMutableArray *valuesArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(NSArray *arr in valuesArray) {
        [valuesArray1 addObject:[arr objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    NSOrderedSet *orderedSet = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:valuesArray1];
    NSArray *arrayWithoutDuplicates = [orderedSet array];

    NSArray *filtered = [muteArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"value Contains[d] %@", [arrayWithoutDuplicates objectAtIndex:0]]];
```

After getting arrayWithoutDuplicates using for loop you can get separate arrays.

Comment: Thanks Phani, But one thing i missed to mention, We can cannot directly compare with "English" or any other, the values are from server and we dont know any value.

Comment: You need to separate an array based on subject name?

Comment: No based on the Value only

Comment: Could you post your excepted result for above example.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure I understand what you are asking for, but I think this should help:

**Objective-C:**

```
//1
NSMutableArray* englishArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray* scienceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray* mathArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

//2
for(int i = 0; i < mainArray.count; i++){
    //3
    if([mainArray[i][0][@"value"] isEqual: @"English"]){
        //4
        [englishArray addObject:mainArray[i]];
    }
    else if([mainArray[i][0][@"value"] isEqual: @"Science"]){
        [scienceArray addObject:mainArray[i]];
    }
    else if([mainArray[i][0][@"value"] isEqual: @"Math"]){
        [mathArray addObject:mainArray[i]];
    }
}
```

**Explanation of above code:**

1. create 3 `NSMutableArrays` to store the three subject arrays.
2. Iterate through all arrays within the mainArray (where mainArray is the full array you provided)
3. To check subject, first access array in mainArray at index i.

eg. mainArray[i] :

```
(
    {
        name = "attribute_Subject";
        value = English;
    },
    {
        name = "attribute_class";
        value = Fourth;
    },
),
```

3.(cont.) Then access 1st element in that array we just accessed. (the first element is the dictionary which contains the subject value)

eg. mainArray[i][0] :

```
{
    name = "attribute_Subject";
    value = English;
},
```

3.(cont.2)Then access the value for key @"value" of that dictionary.

eg. mainArray[i][0][@"value"]:

```
@"English"
```

4.If that key is equal to the one we need, add the array to appropriate subject array.